# REST service based on Spring boot , spring caching with hazelcast failing to handle cache error

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am using Spring boot and hazelcast for my REST service for caching.

I am caching at service layer (API) using spring @Cachable annotation with custom key generator. Every thing works fine except when it throws RuntimeException from custom key generator function it is not handled by custom error class which I have added to handle error scenario.

The custom error class (CacheErrorHandler) that extends org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport overrides all methods to handle GET,PUT,EVICT errors.

In my case I am expecting it to break into handleCacheGetError function if the custom customKeyGenerator throw RuntimeException.

Can any body point me what I am missing here or help to explain is the right way to handle caching error for cache (like HAZELCAST or REDIS etc) with spring annotation (i.e. using @Cachable).

As sample , here is what my API caching looks like

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "TestCache",keyGenerator = "customKeyGenerator")
public Response getAPIResponse(Integer param1){
...
}
```

Similarly , my cache configuration class which extends CachingConfigurerSupport, looks like this

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
...

@Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new CustomHZCacheErrorHandler();
    }
...
}
```

Here CustomHZCacheErrorHandler looks like

```
public class CustomHZCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomHZCacheErrorHandler.class);

    public CustomHZCacheErrorHandler() {
    }

    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        logger.warn("Error while getting cache " + cache.getName() + " for Key " + key);
    }

    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        logger.warn("Error while putting cache " + cache.getName() + " for Key " + key);
    }

    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        logger.warn("Error while evicting cache " + cache.getName() + " for Key " + key);
    }

    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
        logger.warn("Error while clearing cache " + cache.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@NRA, according to Spring Doc, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheErrorHandler.html, `CacheErrorHandler` used only exceptions thrown by the cache provider, nothing else. Not for Key Generator or not even for the exceptions thrown by the annotated method.

Please see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/AbstractCacheInvoker.java#L71

For MVC Controller, Spring has an annotation to help you handle errors: `@ErrorHandler`. You can find more details here: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

If not using MVC, you can define an `Aspect` Bean & handle all errors for that method/class/package. The trick is, `KeyGenerator` called using an interceptor, before the method, so you need to put an aspect to that `KeyGenerator` class as well to catch it.

Please see this working example: https://gist.github.com/gokhanoner/026c2b90fe3a61b93626383a61932395

Note: I didn't test throwing exception from Cache provider side, you most probably need to define `CacheErrorHandler` as well for that part.

Comment: Spring doc you referred make sense to handle error for MVC and error from cache provider. The  github example you referred didn't run  but looking at code it is throwing RuntimeException at Service layer not during keyGeneration i.e. within by generate() function so it is not addressing the problem I am facing. In my case throwing RuntimeException if for any reason the parameters provided are not valid and cannot be used to create cache key. I will try your suggestion to handle it using Aspect but again not sure will that be sufficient to handle the exception ,log and continue in service api.

Comment: @NRA, I copied a running example. I can share the project if you want. If you run the example, this is the exception you got, which captured by the Aspect I created:

Comment: 2017-12-22 13:58:56.625 ERROR 1896 --- [           main] c.e.cachetest.AfterThrowingExample       : handle error for Object org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator.generate(Object,Method,Object[]). Arguments: [com.example.cachetest.DummyService@663411de, public java.lang.String com.example.cachetest.DummyService.get(java.lang.Integer), [Ljava.lang.Object;@63dd899]

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.example.cachetest.CustomKeyGenerator.generate(CacheTestApplication.java:66) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: I got your point, using AOP as shown in your example you can catch error and log but in my case this wouldn't help because the function throwing RuntimeException during KeyGenerator and even if I apply AOP as you suggested it will continue and end up as unhandled and crash the application rather than continuing with rest of application functionality (meaning if caching fail application should not). e.g use below code and see what happens                                              
 public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... params) {
  throw new RuntimeException("11"); }

Comment: After doing more investigation it seems like this requirement of handling exception from custom KeyGenerator (object/function) is not right way/implementation. Although handling exception should be possible it seems like the effort is unnecessary based on fact that the default keyGenerator from spring itself handle it by wrapping null object in object array and assign value 1 as hashcode. For more detail checkout code org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKeyGenerator and SimpleKey. I would still like to know an elegant way to handle this use case for custom keyGenerator.